# There is an awkward spacing in-between span tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In my code I am using bootstrap and adding words to go with the glyphicons. My words are within the span tag and have this awkwardly large space when it is just a normal space.

```
        <div class="first-draft view">
            <h4>First-Draft</h4>
            <img src="img/view.png" alt="City View"/>
            <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"> View Report</span></h5>
            <h6><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"> Compare</span></h6>
        </div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/zbyztda8/

Comment: Because you put space before "View Report" & "Compare" and your word spacing taking more space. i guess. as i have checked in your fiddle.

Comment: set css property for that.   `word-spacing: 0px;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zbyztda8/3/

Comment: No, it should be `word-spacing: 1ex;` or `word-spacing: 1ch;`

Comment: There is something funky about that font. I had to use `word-spacing: -1ex;` to get a normal looking amount of space.

Comment: Yes, I know I have a space there. The glyphicon is too close to the words otherwise. And the word-spacing: 0px; did not work. btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the solution doesn't work, try removing the font-family. I think the spacing is due to font `'Glyphicons Halflings'` . Better way is to have text in separate span without any styling and different span for glyphicon.

HTML:

```
    <div class="first-draft view">
     <h4>First-Draft</h4>

    <img src="img/view.png" alt="City View" />
     <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"> View Report</span></h5>

     <h6><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"> Compare</span></h6>

</div>
<br/>
<div class="first-draft view">
     <h4>First-Draft</h4>

    <img src="img/view.png" alt="City View" />
     <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span><span>View Report</span></h5>

     <h6><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"> Compare</span></h6>

</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zbyztda8/2/

See the last section which doesn't have `font-family` in span tag.